# Batch create/remove with Firebase Real time db

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I use Firebase real time db like so:

```
 createSoldLead(soldLead: SoldLeadModel): void {
    const soldLeadsReference = this.angularFireDatabase.list<SoldLeadModel>(
      `groups/${this.groupId}/soldLeads`
    );

    const leadsReference = this.angularFireDatabase
        .list<SoldLeadModel>(
      `groups/${this.groupId}/leads`
    );

    soldLeadsReference.set(soldLead.id.toString(),soldLead);

    leadsReference.remove(soldLead.id.toString());
  }
```

This is working fine. But how can I do this as a batch create/remove? i.e. make sure they both succeed

I saw [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html). But no idea how to apply it on my use case?

Comment: Do you want to prevent 2 writes or do you want to make sure they both succeed (i.e. have some kind of transaction)?

Comment: @MikeOne I need this `make sure they both succeed` But `transaction` doesn't work here. It is something different on Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: Yep, hence the ‘some kind of’ . This is not easily solved unless you change the datamodel..

Comment: @MikeOne No need to change the data model. Please see the Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a single multi-path update to write multiple nodes at different paths.

The equivalent of your two calls will be something like this:

```
let updates = {};
updates[`groups/${this.groupId}/soldLeads/${soldLead.id}`] = soldLead;
updates[`groups/${this.groupId}/leads/${soldLead.id}`] = null;

firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Setting a node value to `null` removes that node.

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear to me. i.e. where you used this `updates` to tell about the changes to the firebase? And also how to do that with Angularfire instead of this line? `firebase.database().ref().update(soldLead.id.toString());`

Comment: Oops, I passed the wrong object to the database. That should've been `firebase.database().ref().update(updates);`  I fixed it in the answer now too. I don't exactly know the AngularFire syntax, which is why I showed the underlying SDK call, but this looks promising: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/435.

Comment: Awesome. This is an amazing thing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the `AngularFire` version.

```
createSoldLead(soldLead: SoldLeadModel): void {
    const updates = {};

    updates[`groups/${this.groupId}/soldLeads/${soldLead.id.toString()}`] = {
      ...soldLead,
      createdBy: this.createdBy,
      createdDate: this.createdDate,
    };

    updates[`groups/${this.groupId}/leads/${soldLead.id.toString()}`] = null;

    this.angularFireDatabase.object('/').update(updates);
  }
```